# "As I understand correctly..." instead of "If I understand correctly..."

Tags: word-choice

Is the expression "As I understand correctly..." perfectly fine in place of "If I understand correctly..."?

Is it correct English to say something like "As I understand correctly, we should do that" instead of "If I understand correctly, we should do that" when you want someone to confirm your assumption?

Comment: No.  “If” implies doubt or an assumption.  “As” here means “because”

Comment: The phrase is “As I understand it.” I think *as* is a conjunction here and doesn’t mean because.

Comment: "As I understand correctly" is a claim that you are right and not open to others doubting you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression "as I understand it" is quite common, and is usually used before the speaker states her/his understanding of a topic. It can be an invitation for others to offer corrections. The expression "if I understand correctly" is also common and is used in the same way.

The expression "As I understand correctly" is not common, and it sounds like an error resulting from confusing the two earlier expressions. However it is grammatical, and it would mean "because I understand correctly", in other words it would be an assertion that the speaker is correct.